# why does my 'join' function run wrong

Tags: python

```
b=','.join([1,2,3,4,5])
print b
```

I want it to print the string: `'1,2,3,4,5'`

In your answers, please try to use code examples rather than text, because my English is not very good. Thank you.

Comment: It was a problem of types "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
b = ','.join(map(str, [1,2,3,4,5]))
# => '1,2,3,4,5'
```

Python doesn't automatically turn the ints into strings--you have to convert them to strings first, then join them.

Answer (score 7):

`anystring.join` takes an iterable of **STRINGS**, **not** one of integers, which is what you're passing to it!

So, use `','.join(str(x) for x in range(1, 6))` or the like.

Answer (score 4):

The join function expects strings not integers, if you did `b=','.join(["1","2","3","4","5"])` instead it works.

Here's the consoles output:

```
>>> b=','.join(["1","2","3","4","5"])
>>> print b
1,2,3,4,5
>>>
```